# 2nd and 3rd Custom Post Type URL's 404ing

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting

My first CPT saves its URL's exactly as expected. However, I have worked for 2 days on getting my second and third Custom Post Type URL'S to rewrite correctly. They do in fact save as expected in edit.php like this:

```
www.domain.com/things/postname/
```

**However it is 404ing when I view the page.**

I have used

```
global $wp_rewrite;

$projects_structure = '/%things%/';
$wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag("%things%", '([^/]+)', "things=");
$wp_rewrite->add_permastruct('things', $projects_structure, false);
```

**Why won't the other CPT URL's rewrite?** For my "food" CPT I am using

```
'rewrite' => array( 
   'slug' => 'food',
   'with_front' => false,
   'feed'=> true,  
   'pages'=> true 
),
```

and have also tried

```
global $wp_rewrite;

$projects_structure = '/food/%food%/';
$wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag("%food%", '([^/]+)', "food=");
$wp_rewrite->add_permastruct('food_pt', $projects_structure, false);
```

Brand new WP install, 
I have checked my htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I have manually flush_rewrite_rules(); 
and my settings->permalink structure is

```
/%year%/%postname%/
```

I have read everything that Google can get me and just don't get understand. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that

```
global $wp_rewrite;
```

is sitewide as far as I understand but am willing to be informed of the details here. Implementing it with a CPT RUINED my rewrite rules sitewide.

Changing the rewrite=> array('slug'=>'name') should have been where I stayed and back to basics on how to manipulate a CPT's permalink structure.

Comment: Has the community any better answers on CTP URLs?